# What's the complexity of connecting and disconnecting with socket.io?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io

I'm running a `node.js` server. On my website I use different URLs for different pages. For instance:

```
mydomain.com/           -- Index
mydomain.com/register   -- Register
mydomain.com/profile    -- Profile
```

I am using `socket.io` to send chat messages and notifications to the client. However, whenever the user switches page or performs a POST-request the socket connection is disconnected and then reconnected.

I'm wondering what the complexity of socket.io's connect/disconnect functions are and wether it is durable that all clients reconnect their sockets each time they perform an action on my website? I've looked at the documentation for socket.io without finding the answer.

Answer (score 0):

That's what I have found, but I would guess it would really depend on your code.  If each page connects to the channel then the connection will be reestablished.  I am also in the habit of storing messages on the server side to reestablish state - something to this effect:

```
const events = []
const onSomeEvent = function(myEvent) {
      events.push(myEvent)
      socket.emit("onSomeEvent", myEvent)
}
socket.on("connect", function(){
    events.forEach(function(myEvent){
       socket.emit("onSomeEvent", myEvent)
    })
})
```